# Problem Mapping with Folium Map Geolocalization It appears Empty (white screen)

Tags: python, maps, data-science, analytics, folium

I have some trouble with folium map it keeps giving me the result with a full white screen, but the last week it was working.

Here it's a brief of the data:

```
    # Externo   Latitud Longitud    Cliente Conductor   Precio  Zona de tarifa2
0   41881533680 -34.80702300    -56.03360210    (URUGUAYTECHOS2012) Luana y Gabriel Alarcon 205 10
1   41885284633 -34.88799240    -56.18466770    (TINCHOBOTTA)   Rodrigo Santalla    117 6
2   41883616764 -34.88953320    -56.15607280    (STTITIA)   Gustavo Alvarez 117 6
3   41884586262 -34.88609720    -56.16356840    (LORO5135536)   Gaston Alvarez  117 6
4   41885830223 -34.72427530    -56.20121940    (COER7145850)   nicolas ferreira    205 8
```

Here it's the code:

```
df['# Externo'] = df['# Externo'].astype('str')
df['# Externo'] = df['# Externo'].str.slice(0, 11)
df[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = df["Ubicación finalizada"].str.split(",", expand=True)
df[["Latitud","Longitud"]] = df[["Latitud","Longitud"]].astype(float)
df['Cliente'] = df['Cliente'].astype('str')
df['Conductor'] = df['Conductor'].astype('str')
df['Zona de tarifa2'] = df['Zona de tarifa'].str.slice(4, 7)
df["Zona de tarifa1"] = '\n ' + df['Zona de tarifa'].astype('str') + '\n $'+ df['Precio '].astype('str') + '    \n  Conductor:\n ' + df['Conductor'].astype('str') + '\n'+ '    \n Nro Venta:  '+ df['# Externo'].astype('str')
colors= ['lightgray', 'darkred', 'lightgreen', 'green', 'pink', 'darkgreen', 'lightblue', 'darkpurple', 'black', 
'lightred', 'gray', 'orange', 'cadetblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'beige', 'white', 'darkblue', 'red']
df['Zona de tarifa2'] = df['Zona de tarifa2'].astype('int')
df=df.dropna(subset=['Longitud'])
df=df.dropna(subset=['Latitud'])
map = folium.Map(location=[df.Latitud.mean(), df.Longitud.mean()], zoom_start=14, control_scale=True)
for index, location_info in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["Latitud"], location_info["Longitud"]],icon=folium.Icon(color=colors[int(location_info['Zona de tarifa2'])]),popup=location_info["Cliente"]+'\n '+location_info["Zona de tarifa1"]).add_to(map)
map
```

All the definitions are working properly but the map is still white. I can't find a solution a tried different browsers but still not work!
Hope someone can help me!

Best regards!
-- Sorry for bad english!

Comment: I was able to draw a map using only the data in the question. I ran the following code with the color list enabled. `m = folium.Map(location=[df.Latitud.mean(), df.Longitud.mean()], zoom_start=12, control_scale=True)
for index, location_info in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["Latitud"], location_info["Longitud"]],
                  icon=folium.Icon(color=colors[int(location_info['Zona de tarifa2'])]),
                  popup=location_info["Cliente"]+'\n '+str(location_info["Zona de tarifa2"])
                 ).add_to(m)
m`

Comment: Using your's is still white screen :(

Comment: Confirmed! Thanks!